# gsoap : how to solve namespace error when referencing a group

Tags: c++, xsd, xml-namespaces, gsoap

I have two xsd files "hardware.xsd" and "GPU.xsd", both with different target namespaces, and both elementFormDefault qualified.

xmlns:hardware="urn:hardware" and xmlns:gpu="urn:gpu".

**hardware.xsd**

```
<xsd:complexType name="ComputerSettings">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:group ref="gpu:myGPU"/>
      ...
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

**GPU.xsd**

```
<xsd:group name="myGPU">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Frequence" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="DedicatedMemory" type="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
<xsd:group/>
```

With this two files, the gsoap schema importer generates a ComputerSettings class, with the attributes Frequence and DedicatedMemory, but he doesn't prefix them with the gpu prefix. So when I send my request then end up in the hardware prefix, and I get a namespace mismatch.

When I delete the group and just declare the two elements Frequence and DedicatedMemory, and in the other files I referenced this two element one by one, it works perfectly. The namespace prefix shows in the header file.

In this case I can replace the group reference, but I have a case in which there is multiple element with the same name in the same target namespace. So the group was here to create a kind of sub-namespace. And so I am able to reference the right element.

Is it a problem with the gsoap tools, or is there a solution?

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE**

**header.h** (With group reference)

```
 class hardware__ComputerSettings{ 
 public:
 //  BEGIN GROUP <xs:group name="myGPU">
 /// Element "Frequence" of XSD type xs:string.
     std::string                          Frequence                      1;  ///<         Required element.
 /// Element "DedicatedMemory" of XSD type xs:string.
     std::string                          DedicatedMemory                1;  ///< Required element.
 //  END OF GROUP
 /// A handle to the soap struct that manages this instance (automatically set).
     struct soap                         *soap                          ;
 };
```

Here the importation only with element references :

**hardware.xsd**

```
<xsd:complexType name="ComputerSettings">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Frequence" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="DedicatedMemory" type="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

**GPU.xsd**

```
<xsd:element name="Frequence" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="DedicatedMemory" type="xsd:string"/>
```

**header.h** (Notice the gpu namespace before the variable names)

```
class hardware__ComputerSettings
{ public:
/// Element reference "urn:hardware:""urn:gpu":Frequence.
    std::string                          gpu__Frequence                 1;  ///< Required element.
/// Element reference "urn:hardware:""urn:gpu":DedicatedMemory.
    std::string                          gpu__DedicatedMemory           1;  ///< Required element.
/// A handle to the soap struct that manages this instance (automatically set).
    struct soap                         *soap                          ;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has a [section that explains how to use gSoap with multiple namespaces](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.34). You can also [customize and optimize the type bindings by specifying prefixes you prefer](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#sec:typemap).

In the distribution, there are examples that you can use to see how it is done, quote:

> Both approaches are demonstrated by example in the gSOAP distribution, the samples/link (C only) and samples/link++ (C++ with C++ namespaces) examples.

Comment: I had a look at the samples but I think it isn't my problem. I have juste one client application. And I already modified the typemap file with my own prefix, but it just renames the namespace, it doesn't solve the conflict.

My problem is that the gsoap schema importer(wsdl2h), considers the elements Frequence and DedicatedMemory as a part of the hardware namespace, but it should be in the gpu one.